# Is it possible to read the contents of a flat file into a pl/sql table (not a regular table)?

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 12.2 and want to read a txt/xls/etc-File (Flat File). Is it possible to read the contents of the file into a pl/sql table (not a regular table)? 
The challenge is, not to modify the database, especially not to create any database object. At the same time I have to work with the contents of the flat file in pl/sql. That's why I want to read the flat file and just keep it 'as a table in memory'. 
I'm working with sql*plus and sql developer.

What I want to do is about data migration: Read data from a given database and write them into csv-files in order to import these files into a new software. While doing this, some of the data has to be 'translated' (mapping): I read a value from the old software and translate it into a value that the new software is able to read. These Mapping-Files are the flat files I am talking about. My (not yet existing) plsql or sql code should read the old value, open the flat file and fetch the record with old and new value and then work with the new value and store it together with the other data in a file.

Comment: Your best bet would be to create an external table on the database and read your file via that, but I appreciate that requires adding a database object. Why can't you create a database object, and why do you need to process the file in PL/SQL in the first place? Is it an ad-hoc thing, or something that will be run regularly. Is it supposed to update data in the already-present tables?

Comment: Once you can read a file in the first place - which needs a directory object pointing to the location on the server that the file exists, so hopefully that already exists and has the right privileges - you can do whatever you want with the contents. Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: @Boneist Not to create any new database objects is kind of a policy at the working environment I'm in. It's nothing that will run regularly but perhaps a few times and it only will perform queries.

Comment: is it supposed to run automatically, or is it a manual task? Can you update your question to given an example of the contents (we don't care what the content is, as long as it's representative), and what you need to do with them, please?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! @Boneist It's a manual task. Question is updated now but there's no code written at this time

Comment: I think you'd be far better off writing a program outside of the database that can either query the database or read from a file containing the data from the database, and read the input file, do the necessary processing and output the resultant file. If you're not allowed to create objects in the database due to "a policy" (which is, IMO, bonkers; they've asked to you do a job and simultaneously prevented you from doing said job.), you either have to pull the data from the database and process it outside of the database, or you have to put the contents of the file into a select statement...

Comment: ... and use that to query against your table in the database. If your file is large, that's probably going to be untenable, so I'd stick with processing the data outside of the database in this case.

Comment: If upgrading is an option then Oracle 18c allows for [inline external tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/inline-external-tables-18c), where an external table can be defined in a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help, however it needs manual processing.

```
declare
  f UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  ldir varchar2(100) := 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
  lfile varchar2(100) := 'writefile.sql';
  vtable m_code_tabletype := m_code_tabletype();
BEGIN
f := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(ldir,lfile,'R');
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(f) THEN
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(f,lfile);
        IF lfile IS NULL THEN
          EXIT;
        END IF;
         --do parsing
         -- col1, col2, ...
         vtable.extend;
         vtable(vtable.count) := m_code_object(col1, col2, ...);
      END;
    END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks @Simonare, using an existing folder, this could work, building the pl sql table in the loop.

Comment: I am glad that It helped you. If you think that this answer is useful for you please consider to mark it as answer so the community can also benefit from it